# Not able to start the docker container for postfix

Tags: dockerfile, postfix-mta

I am getting the below error when i try to run the docker container for postfix

```
2020-05-29 08:49:05,837 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
2020-05-29 08:49:05,837 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
2020-05-29 08:49:05,844 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2020-05-29 08:49:05,844 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2020-05-29 08:49:05,844 INFO supervisord started with pid 17
2020-05-29 08:49:06,852 INFO spawned: 'postfix' with pid 19
2020-05-29 08:49:06,856 INFO spawnerr: can't find command 'rsyslogd'
2020-05-29 08:49:07,167 INFO exited: postfix (exit status 1; not expected)
2020-05-29 08:49:08,172 INFO spawned: 'postfix' with pid 136
2020-05-29 08:49:08,174 INFO spawnerr: can't find command 'rsyslogd'
2020-05-29 08:49:08,219 INFO exited: postfix (exit status 1; not expected)
2020-05-29 08:49:10,230 INFO spawned: 'postfix' with pid 151
2020-05-29 08:49:10,233 INFO spawnerr: can't find command 'rsyslogd'
2020-05-29 08:49:10,274 INFO exited: postfix (exit status 1; not expected)
2020-05-29 08:49:13,283 INFO spawned: 'postfix' with pid 166
2020-05-29 08:49:13,286 INFO spawnerr: can't find command 'rsyslogd'
2020-05-29 08:49:13,286 INFO gave up: rsyslog entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2020-05-29 08:49:13,325 INFO exited: postfix (exit status 1; not expected)
2020-05-29 08:49:14,330 INFO gave up: postfix entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

The block corresponding to the above is

```
command=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -c3
```

Kindly help

Thanks,
Suv

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the dockerfile or `docker run` commandline

Comment: please provide the container config you are using to run this.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the container config you are using to run.

Coming to what I understood was, I guess `rsyslog` is not installed in the container, so please install it before using it. If you are on a Debian or ubuntu container use the below commands to install it in the container.

```sh
add-apt-repository ppa:adiscon/v8-stable 
apt-get install rsyslog
```

In dockerfile:

```sh
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:adiscon/v8-stable && \
apt-get -y install rsyslog
```